# nicer typesetting of some subreaction

Tags: amsmath

I hope that this question is not a duplicate but I could not find it on this forum. I'd like to typeset a reaction as displayed here:

[image]

However, what I got is rather ugly, and my question is whether there are some better options. This is the code to produce it:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align}
     \pi^+~\to~&\mu^++\nu_\mu\notag\\
     &\,\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Lsh$}\, e^++\bar\nu_\mu+\nu_e\;.
    \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to have a more reasonable output, i.e. larger arrow which is also closer to \mu^+ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option.

```
\begin{align}
\pi^+~\to~&\mu^++\nu_\mu\notag\\[-.7ex]
& \put(3.5,2.5){\line(0,1){10}}\to e^++\bar\nu_\mu+\nu_e\;.
\end{align}
```

[image]

If you want the arrow to start closer to the `\mu` you can make the `-.7` more negative. Adjust the length of the vertical part of the arrow by changing the 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\drsh` symbol  from `mathabx`. Here is how to load it without loading the full `mathabx` fonts (which would replace  the symbol fonts from `amsmath`). I also replaced `\to` with `\longrightarrow`, and removed the unbreakble spaces. See if it corresponds to what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

 \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathb5 <6-7> mathb6 <7-8> mathb7
<8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9
<10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\drsh}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"EB}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \pi^+ \longrightarrow{} &\mu^+ + \nu_\mu\notag\\
 & \drsh e^+ +\bar \nu_\mu + \nu_e\;.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your method is quite useful! However, I still wonder if there is a simple way of getting a somewhat larger symbol, which is also closer to the \mu^+. Ideally the arrow head of the lower arrow would be as large as the arrowhead of \longrightarrow.